# Where to add business logic for phtml template files that reside under modules in design dir?

Tags: magento2, phtml

I have a template file that resides under app/design/frontend//theme/Magento_Sales/templates/order/email_invoice_totals.phtml

As I understand, the business logic should not reside in those template files. Below is, I have the code for that phtml file.

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals;

/** @var Totals $block */
/** @var Escaper $escaper */
$index = 0;
$totalsData = $block->getTotals();
function arrayElementPositionChange($key, $new_index, $array)
{
    if($new_index < 0) return;
    if($new_index >= count($array)) return;
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $array)) return;

    $ret = array();
    $ind = 0;
    foreach($array as $k => $v)
    {
        if($new_index == $ind)
        {
            $ret[$key] = $array[$key];
            $ind++;
        }
        if($k != $key)
        {
            $ret[$k] = $v;
            $ind++;
        }
    }
    if($new_index == $ind)
        $ret[$key] = $array[$key];
    return $ret;
}
$totalsData = arrayElementPositionChange('tax', 1, $totalsData) ? array_move('tax', 1, $totalsData) : $block->getTotals();

?>
<?php foreach ($totalsData as $_code => $_total): ?>
    <?php $index = $index+1;  ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
        <?=
            dd($block->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName()));
            $htmlBlock = $block->getTotals($_total->getBlockName(), false);
        ?>
    <?php else:?>
        <tr class="<?php if ($_code == "grand_total"): ?> <?= "grand-total"?><?php elseif ($_code === "subtotal_excl"):?> <?= "subtotal-excl" ?> <?php else:?> <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_code);?><?php endif; ?>">
            <th class=<?= $index == count($block->getTotals()) ? "tax-history" : "row-history"?> <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getLabelProperties() ?> scope="row">
                <?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel()) ?>
            </th>
            <td class=<?= $index == count($block->getTotals()) ? "total-sum-history" : "price-history"?> <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getValueProperties() ?> data-th="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_total->getLabel()) ?>">
                <span class="total">&euro; <?= number_format($_total['value'], 2, '.', ''); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

As seen, I have a function called arrayElementPositionChange() but, it should not be inside the template file. So, the question is, where should I add this business logic? and then use it in my phtml file?

One more question is that, I have

```
$block->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false);
```

Here, the child html for is getting fetched. How can I find the child html's phtml file and manipulate it? I want to make some changes inside that html that is returned using getChildHtml method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Question 1.**
   There are 2 cases:

- Case 1: If you **already** use a custom block class which extend `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals` block class for your phtml template file, you should add your business logic in that block.
- Case 2: If you use default block (`Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals`) for your phtml template file, you should use a ViewModel class.

Assume you vendor name is **Vendor** and your module name is **Module**.

In your layout xml file which declare `Magento_Sales::order/email_invoice_totals.phtml`, inject the ViewModel class.
For example:

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Invoice\Totals" name="email_invoice_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/email_invoice_totals.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <!-- other arguments -->
        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\ViewModel\ElementPositionChange</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Create ViewModel class:
File path: app/code/Vendor/Module/ViewModel/ElementPositionChange.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class ElementPositionChange implements ArgumentInterface
{
    public function getTotalsWithElementPositionChange($key, $newIndex, $totalsData)
    {
        if ($newIndex < 0) return;
        if ($newIndex >= count($totalsData)) return;
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $totalsData)) return;

        $result = [];
        $ind = 0;
        foreach ($totalsData as $k => $v) {
            if ($newIndex == $ind) {
                $result[$key] = $totalsData[$key];
                $ind++;
            }
            if ($k != $key) {
                $result[$k] = $v;
                $ind++;
            }
        }
        if ($newIndex == $ind)
            $result[$key] = $totalsData[$key];
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then in your phtml template, replace

```
$totalsData = arrayElementPositionChange('tax', 1, $totalsData) ? array_move('tax', 1, $totalsData) : $block->getTotals();
```

with the code below:

```
$totalsData = $block->getViewModel()->getTotalsWithElementPositionChange('tax', 1, $totalsData) ? array_move('tax', 1, $totalsData) : $block->getTotals();
```

2. **Question 2.**
   Assume you using `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals` block class for your phtml template file. To find the child html's phtml file of that block you should go to layout files which assigned `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals` class to your phtml template file, you will see the `template` attribute in child blocks which declare `block` node.

For example, the block in the below code has `tax` block as child and it declare template file is `Magento_Tax::order/tax.phtml`.

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="4" class="mark"</argument>
        <argument name="value_properties" xsi:type="string">class="amount"</argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Tax::order/tax.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Some cases, multiple layout files declares child blocks for a parent block. You can run this command from your Magento root to know which files reference to the parent block:

```
grep -r --include \*.xml "Magento\\\Sales\\\Block\\\Order\\\Totals" app vendor
```

Answer (score 1):

ViewModels is what you are looking for.

Please check the official documentation, if you can't solve it please add a comment.

[Check view models at adobe.com](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/view-models/)